# Can't add JMenuBar to Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jmenubar

I'm trying to add a menu to my `Applet` however I get a compilation error. I can't figure out why. Can someone help me?

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class app extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar ();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu ("Help");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        JMenuItem   mItem = new JMenuItem ("Log out");
        menu.add(mItem);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? Add it to your question. This will help us help you.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class app extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar ();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu ("Help");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        JMenuItem   mItem = new JMenuItem ("Log out");
        menu.add(mItem);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

That would work but for a `J` in there to denote a **Swing** applet.

```
public class app extends JApplet {

    // ..
```

Comment: Aha I got it. Thank you

Comment: *"Aha I got it"* Glad you got it sorted. :) I also highly recommend the advice of @J.Chomel about copy/pasting the error information. Every little bit helps us to spot the problem faster. ;)

Comment: Will do next time. Thank you again.